# $x^T(Q-I)x\geq 0 \Rightarrow x^T(Q^{-1}-I)x) \leq 0$ verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the condition that $Q$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix with all entries positive and it is NOT symmetric. It is given that $x^T(Q-I)x \geq 0\,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. My doubt is, can we show that $x^T(Q^{-1}-I)x\leq 0$.

I tried proving this in the following manner:

As $Q$ is invertible, its square root exists, then $\forall\, x,\,\exists \,y$ such that $x=Q^{-1/2}y$. 
Thus, $y^TQ^{{-1/2}^T}(Q-I)Q^{-1/2}y\geq 0\,\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (**this is where I am worried, can we say $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$??**) 
$\Rightarrow y^T(I-Q^{-1})y\geq 0\,\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

In short, my doubt is if $Q$ is an invertible matrix with positive entries, does square root exist in the set of real matrices?

Comment: Since $x$ is bound, it does not matter what you call it. I would say your proof is correct — assuming that the assumption that a square root exists is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $S=Q+Q^T-I$ and $K=Q-Q^T$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\forall x,\ x^T(Q-I)x\ge0
&\Leftrightarrow (Q-I)+(Q^T-I)\succeq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow S\succeq I\\
&\Leftrightarrow \lambda_\min(S)\ge1
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\forall x,\ x^T(Q^{-1}-I)x\le0
&\Leftrightarrow (Q^{-1}-I)+(Q^{-1}-I)^T\preceq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow Q(Q^{-1}-I)Q^T+Q(Q^{-1}-I)^TQ^T\preceq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow Q+Q^T-2QQ^T\preceq0\\
&\Leftrightarrow (2Q-I)(2Q-I)^T\succeq I\\
&\Leftrightarrow (S+K)(S+K)^T\succeq I\\
&\Leftrightarrow \sigma_\min(S+K)\ge 1.
\end{aligned}
Therefore it suffices to show that $\lambda_\min(S)\ge1\Rightarrow\sigma_\min(S+K)\ge 1$ whenever $S$ is symmetric and $K$ is skew-symmetric.

Suppose $\lambda_\min(S)\ge1$. Let $u$ and $v$ be respectively a left and a right unit singular vector corresponding to the minimum singular value of $S+K$, so that $(S+K)v=\sigma_\min(S+K)u$. Then
$$
1\le\lambda_\min(S)\le v^TSv=v^T(S+K)v=\sigma_\min(S+K)v^Tu\le\sigma_\min(S+K).
$$
Now we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was struggling with it. Each line is perfect. I would love to know how you got the intuition behind using the singular values to prove the inequality.

Comment: @user812951 Since $x^TMx$ depends only only the symmetric part of $M$, it is natural to decompose a matrix into its symmetric part and skew-symmetric part to see what happens.